# Compilation error when passing functional object and its arguments to std::thread constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile the following code, but on the line `threads[i] = std::thread(find_elements[i], block_start, block_end, match);` the `std::thread` object cannot be constructed with given arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <future>

class join_threads
{
public:
  explicit join_threads(std::vector<std::thread>& threads)
    : threads_(threads) {}

  ~join_threads()
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads_.size(); ++i)
    {
      if(threads_[i].joinable())
      {
        threads_[i].join();
      }
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::thread>& threads_;
};

template <typename Iterator, typename MatchType>
Iterator parallel_find(Iterator first, Iterator last, MatchType match)
{
  class find_element
  {
  public:
    void operator()(Iterator begin, Iterator end, MatchType match)
    {
      try
      {
        while (begin != end)
        {
          if (*begin == match)
          {
            result_.set_value(begin);
            is_found_ = true;
            return;
          }
          ++begin;
        }
        result_.set_value(end);
      }
      catch(...)
      {
        result_.set_exception(std::current_exception());
      }
    }

    Iterator get() { return result_.get_future().get(); }
    bool is_found() const { return is_found_; }

  private:
    std::promise<Iterator> result_;
    bool is_found_ = false;
  };

  const unsigned length = std::distance(first, last);

  if (0 == length) return last;

  const unsigned min_per_thread = 25;
  const unsigned max_threads = (length + min_per_thread - 1) / min_per_thread;
  const unsigned hardware_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  const unsigned num_threads = std::min(
        hardware_threads != 0 ? hardware_threads : 2, max_threads);
  const unsigned block_size = length / num_threads;

  std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads - 1);
  std::vector<find_element> find_elements(num_threads);

  {
    join_threads joiner(threads);
    Iterator block_start = first;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_threads - 1; ++i)
    {
      Iterator block_end = block_start;
      std::advance(block_end, block_size);
      threads[i] = std::thread(find_elements[i], block_start, block_end, match);
      block_start = block_end;
    }

    find_elements[num_threads - 1](block_start, last, match);
  }

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_threads - 1; ++i)
  {
    if (find_elements[i].is_found())
    {
      return find_elements[i].get();
    }
  }

  return find_elements[num_threads - 1].get();
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
  parallel_find(v.begin(), v.end(), 9);

  return 0;
}
```

The exact error produced by **clang++** version **3.9.1** is the following:

```
In file included from ../../../sources/test/main.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/thread:39:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/functional:1379:11: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::tuple<find_element, __normal_iterator<int *, vector<int, allocator<int> > >, __normal_iterator<int *, vector<int, allocator<int> > >, int>'
        : _M_bound(std::forward<_Tp>(__f), std::forward<_Up>(__args)...)
          ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/functional:1426:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Bind_simple<find_element (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int)>::_Bind_simple<const find_element &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, int &>' requested here
      return __result_type(
             ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/thread:137:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__bind_simple<find_element &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, int &>' requested here
              std::__bind_simple(std::forward<_Callable>(__f),
                   ^
../../../sources/test/main.cpp:84:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::thread::thread<find_element &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, int &>' requested here
      threads[i] = std::thread(find_elements[i], block_start, block_end, match);
                   ^
../../../sources/test/main.cpp:105:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'parallel_find<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int>' requested here
  parallel_find(v.begin(), v.end(), 9);
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:600:18: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Dummy = void]
                 _TCC<_Dummy>::template
                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:611:18: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Dummy = void]
                 _TCC<_Dummy>::template
                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:628:5: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _UElements = <const find_element &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, int &>]
                  _TC<sizeof...(_UElements) == 1, _Elements...>::template
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:641:5: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _UElements = <const find_element &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, int &>]
                  _TC<sizeof...(_UElements) == 1, _Elements...>::template
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:737:19: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Alloc = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _UElements = <__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, int &>]
        enable_if<_TMC<_UElements...>::template
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:748:19: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Alloc = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _UElements = <__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &, int &>]
        enable_if<_TMC<_UElements...>::template
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:579:17: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 4 were provided
      constexpr tuple()
                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:589:26: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 4 were provided
      explicit constexpr tuple()
                         ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:670:19: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__in', but 4 arguments were provided
        constexpr tuple(const tuple<_UElements...>& __in)
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:682:28: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__in', but 4 arguments were provided
        explicit constexpr tuple(const tuple<_UElements...>& __in)
                           ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:694:19: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__in', but 4 arguments were provided
        constexpr tuple(tuple<_UElements...>&& __in)
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:705:28: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__in', but 4 arguments were provided
        explicit constexpr tuple(tuple<_UElements...>&& __in)
                           ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:721:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 6 arguments, but 4 were provided
        tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a,
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:732:11: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 6 arguments, but 4 were provided
        explicit tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a,
                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:711:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
        tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a)
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:759:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
        tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a, const tuple& __in)
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:763:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
        tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a, tuple&& __in)
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:772:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
        tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a,
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:784:11: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
        explicit tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a,
                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:796:2: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
        tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a,
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:808:11: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
        explicit tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a,
                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:654:17: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
      constexpr tuple(tuple&&) = default; 
                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/tuple:652:17: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
      constexpr tuple(const tuple&) = default;
                ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  done

Comment: The `std::promise` within the `find_element` helper class [isn't copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/promise). When you pass in `find_elements[i]` to the `std::thread` constructor, it will try to internally copy the given functor, hence the error. You can either pass it in via `std::ref` and ensure to manage the lifetime(s) of the `find_element` structures as the threads are operating on them, or you can just use `std::async` directly if all you want is to have a query-able/waitable `std::future`.

Comment: @Alejandro You know there is an answer section right? On a related note, this is probably a compiler bug, as the function object shouldn't be copied.

Comment: @Rakete1111, Yes I'm aware, just probing for discussion first =) It was my understanding however that `std::thread` will store its passed arguments by value (cv-ref disqualified) and construct them by `std::forward`. So if you pass in the functor by lvalue-reference, the copy is warranted. That's why I suggested the `reference_wrapper` approach.

Comment: @Alejandro Nope, `std::thread` should forward the arguments, yes, and call invoke on it. Forwarding the function doesn't copy it, it doesn't store it. Anyways, [`Callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) doesn't mention anything about being copy constructible, so the code should compile.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I modified the code to be self-sufficient.

Comment: @Alejandro You are right. Using `std::ref` for the function object solves the problem. I tested with **clang** and **gcc** and both compilers have this behavior and because of this the issue probably in not a compiler bug. I'm only not sure about whether this is bug in the standard library because I think that on linux both compilers shared single standard library implementation. If you post your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Can you tell me with which exact compiler and standard library implementation you are testing?

Comment: @bobeff gcc 6.2.1. Interesting, I would still bet on a bug though, cppreference doesn't say anything about how `f` should be copyable.

Comment: @Rakete1111, [N4606](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf) does mention that the function and any arguments in the parameter pack shall meet the `MoveConstructible` concept and will be passed to `std::invoke` as if by `decay_copy`.

Comment: @Rakete1111, I also noticed that you didn't instantiate the `parallel_find` function template in your "It compiles fine" comment, so of course the errors would never manifest. Try adding a simple invocation of the `parallel_find` function and you'll see it fail catastrophically, leading to the diagnosis of trying to access the deleted copy constructor of `std::promise<T>`.

Comment: @Alejandro No way! I'm dumb... Ok but where did you find the reference which says that `std::thread` stores its functor? Standard? Thanks